# When opening terminal, mail window pops up

Tags: mac

Does anybody know why when I open a new terminal window/session/tab, the mail app opens (if completely close) or pops up on Mac Monterey 12.5.

I can not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the terminal is (mis)configured to open it instead of a shell. Or the terminal runs a shell but one of the startup scripts of the shell opens the window. Do you even get a shell? Or do you get a shell only when you close the mail window? Or do you get a shell and the window simultaneously? What is the virtual terminal? What is the shell?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I use zsh, and the exact moment I start a new shell the Mail app stars. I check also the "Log in option" but there is nothing on that side

Comment: Does your `zsh` actually give you a prompt? If it does, what happens when you run (another) `zsh` from the inside of `zsh`?

Comment: If I run a new ```zsh``` inside the already open ```zsh``` Mail pops up

Comment: Most likely something in some startup script. I don't know `zsh` enough to tell you what scripts to check. Hopefully someone more familiar with the shell will write an answer or guide you further in your research. A good thing for you to do now is to [edit] the question and put all the information from your comments into the question body.

Comment: I'm so sorry. There was a "bug" in the zshrc... I created an alias that opens the Mail app. I don't know why, inside the zsh that same alias was been called.
I'm so sorry to have waist your time @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: No harm done. I'm a *volunteer* and I'm here to help.